# Calculating availability on Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have stored system logs in my Oracle DB. The logs have start/end dates.
I need to calculate the uptime/downtime of this certain system. 
The problem is, what if there are several logs at the same time?
For example:
log1 start_date: 8am end_date: 10am
log2 start_date: 9am end_date: 10.30am
I'd like to get 2.5hrs of downtime.
Any ideas of how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by identifying overlapping periods and then grouping them.  The idea is to create a flag whenever a group does not overlap and then do a cumulative sum of the flags.  Something like this should work to get uptime and downtime:

```
select system_id, min(start_date) as start_date, max(start_date) as end_date
from (select l.*, sum(IsStart) over (order by start_date) as grp
      from (select l.*,
                   (case when lag(end_date) over (partition by systemid, start_date) >= start_date
                         then 0
                         else 1
                    end) as IsStart
            from logs l
           ) l
     ) l
group by system_id, grp;
```

You can then aggregate this to get the information you want, something like:

```
select system_id, sum(end_date - start_date) as uptime,
       max(end_date) - min(start_date) = sum(end_date - start_time) as downtime
from (select system_id, min(start_date) as start_date, max(start_date) as end_date
      from (select l.*, sum(IsStart) over (order by start_date) as grp
            from (select l.*,
                         (case when lag(end_date) over (partition by systemid, start_date) >= start_date
                               then 0
                               else 1
                          end) as IsStart
                  from logs l
                 ) l
           ) l
      group by stem_id, grp
     ) l
group by system_id;
```

This assumes that the periods don't overlaps and you don't care about systems with no log records.